# Phone Prices problem (october challenge Codechef)

Tags: c++

problem statement: https://www.codechef.com/OCT19B/problems/S10E
my solution works for all the test cases that i have tried on my IDE but codechef says its wrong. I am fairly new to programming so help me out in figuring whats wrong.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<string>
#include<sstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int t, n, arr[5];
    string p;
    cin >> t;
    vector<int> v;
    int m = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
        int gdcount = 0;

        //intialising temporary array part
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            arr[j] = 751;
        }

        //taking input as per number of n test cases
        cin >> n;
        cin.ignore();
        getline(cin, p);
        stringstream ss;
        ss << p;
        string temp;
        int g;
        for (int x = 0; x < n; x++) {
            ss >> temp;
            if (stringstream(temp) >> g) {
                v.push_back(g);
            }
        }

        //checking and storing good days in gdcount variable
        for (auto k = v.begin(); k < v.end(); k++) {
            int count = 0;
            for (int l = 0; l < 5; l++) {
                if (*k > arr[l]) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
            if(count == 0){
                gdcount++;
            }
            arr[m] = *k;
            m++;
            if (m >= 5) {
                m = 0;
            }
        }
        cout << gdcount << endl;
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your test `*k > arr[l]` appears to be incorrect.  When this test passes you are saying "the current price `*k` is *not* a good price if it is larger than a price in the previous five days".

However, the definition of a good price is different:

> Chef considers the price of the phone to be *good* if it is strictly smaller than all the prices he has observed during the previous five days.

So in fact, the test for "not a good price" should include those that are **equal to** `*k` as well.

In other words, your test should be:

```
for (int l = 0; l < 5; l++) {
    if (*k >= arr[l]) {
        count++;
    }
}
```

It's pretty much a guarantee that exercises like this will use inputs that test boundary conditions.  But they will often give you examples that do not test those conditions.  This helps you develop your "programmer's eye" for accurately capturing detail and making sure you construct your own tests.

---

### Additional notes:

- It is incorrect to use the `<` operator to test iterators, as you are currently doing like this:

  ```
  for (auto k = v.begin(); k < v.end(); k++) ...
  ```

  Instead, you must test against `end` using `!=`:

  ```
  for (auto k = v.begin(); k != v.end(); k++) ...
  ```
- There is no reason to add up the number of prices that are bad.  You simply need to know if *any* are bad.  You could simply do this:

  ```
  bool goodPrice = true;
  for (int l = 0; l < 5; l++) {
      if (*k >= arr[l]) {
          goodPrice = false;
          break;               // No need to do any further tests
      }
  }
  ```

  Another way to do this is with `std::any_of` or `std::all_of`.  For example:

  ```
  bool goodPrice = std::all_of(arr, arr+5, [k](int p) { return p < *k; });
  ```

Comment: It is not incorrect to use `<` for [RandomAccessIterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator), which is the iterator `std::vector` use. It's more generic to use `!=`, but using `<` will not break your code. If the iterator does not support `<`, the compiler will tell you.

Comment: As you pointed out I have tried the boundary condition but the answer still seems to be wrong

Comment: It also looks like you're not clearing the vector between tests, so each test will just add new values to the previous test.  Either move the vector definition into the loop, or call `v.clear()` before populating it.  Did you never run your program with more than one test case as input?